# Levels of Measurement - Comparing Scores from Different Tests

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

Let's say a student takes a set of tests, each with different difficulties of multiple choice questions and a different amount of questions.

If I take the percentage of each test, how can I compare them?

E.g. Can I say based on the difference of percentages between "test A" and "test B", the student did a "difference of percentage" better on "test a"?

When comparing the different percentages, what level of measurement would it be? Ordinal, interval, or rational?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing Scores Normalized Against Maximum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805271/comparing-scores-normalized-against-maximum)

Comment: @VictorS. These are different? One is scores taken from different tests, the other is scores of questions within a test.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO if the two tests have different degrees of difficulty then it is not meaningful to compare the percent correct on test A with the percent correct on test B. 50% could be a great score on test A and a terrible score on test B, yet the difference is zero.