# Comparing Scores Normalized Against Maximum

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

This question stems from this post here: [Levels of Measurement - Comparing Scores from Different Tests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805126/levels-of-measurement-comparing-scores-from-different-tests/3805176#3805176)

Consider a student takes a test, and each question has a score divided by the maximum score of the question (e.g. $5/10$, $1/3$, etc.).

How can I compare the $5/10$ against the $1/3$? Can I compare the ratios of these normalizations?
Or can I only compare the order (e.g. $5/10$ is greater than 1/3)?

What about comparing the differences (e.g. $5/10 - 1/3$)?

In my head, it seems that only comparing order is meaningful because they are not normalized against the same quantities. Is this thinking correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, don't create two questions about the same thing.

Comment: This video may help you: https://en.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/density-curves-normal-distribution-ap/measuring-position/v/comparing-with-z-scores?modal=1

Comment: @VictorS. What if you do not know the mean or standard deviation or normalized distribution? How do you find it?

Comment: Then you don’t use the method used in the video, i guess. I do not know what else you could do.